# Vis.js timeline item align property not working

Tags: javascript, timeline, vis.js

I have a timeline written in JS using the [Vis.js library](https://github.com/visjs/vis-timeline)

I want some specific items on the timeline to be aligned on the left of the line and some on the right side.

Due to the [documentation](https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/docs/timeline/#items) for Vis.js timeline, property `align` of item should override the global `align` property of options for timeline. But it does not.

item example:

```
var items = [];

var item = {
  align: "left"
  date: "20.09.2019"
  eventId: 440
  heading: "Event"
  id: "86ad4f21-6235-46e0-b5c9-29a6d2c16f50"
  nodeType: "single-node"
  start: "2019-09-20T04:00:00"
}

items.push(item);

// create dataset
var dataset = new vis.DataSet(items);
```

timeline options:

```
var options = {
  orientation: 'top',
  min: "2019-09-20T04:00:00",
  max: "2019-09-25T04:00:00",
  start: "2019-09-20T04:00:00",
  end: "2019-09-25T04:00:00",
  align: 'left'
}
```

here is how i update the item align property after calling the `vis.Timeline` constructor:

```
var visualization = document.getElementById('visualization');

var timeline = new vis.Timeline(visualization, dataset, options);

timeline.itemsData.forEach(function(dataItem) {
  if (dataItem.eventId === 440) {
    dataItem.align = 'right';
    timeline.itemsData.update(dataItem, {
      fieldId: "eventId"
    })
  }
})
```

Thanks for any advice :-)

EDIT:

Fixed in https://github.com/visjs/vis-timeline/pull/205

Comment: Created issue on [Github](https://github.com/visjs/vis-timeline/issues/29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me, See https://codepen.io/Enirdas/pen/rNaKxOz

the global Option is set to align:'left'.

Item 2 align option is set to 'right' and it overwrides the global option. The **right end** of item 2 content is aligned with the date. (feb 11, 1990)

```
var container = document.getElementById('visualization');

  // Create a DataSet (allows two way data-binding)
  var items = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, align:'left', content: 'Poland withdraws from Warsaw Pact', start: new Date(1990, 00,01),type:'box'},
    {id: 2, align:'right', content: 'Nelson Mandela released after 27 years imprisonment in South Africa', start: new Date(1990, 01,11),type:'box'},
  ]);

  // Configuration for the Timeline

var options = {
  start: '1990-01-01',
  min: '1988-01-01',
  max: '2015-01-01',
  width: '100%',
  height: '230px',
  zoomMax: 31536000000000,
  zoomMin: 4233600000, 
  align:'left',
  margin: {
    item: 20
  }
};
  // Create a Timeline
  var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
```

Comment: Thanks that you have reminded me about this. It seems that they have fixed it according to https://github.com/visjs/vis-timeline/pull/205